# "Value was either too large or too small for a UInt64" using a .PFX Certificate

Tags: asp.net, certificate

I am using Webpay, which is Chilean most used payment platform to accept Credit Card. I have done that succesfully in the past (on 4 websites) but on my latest one things are not going as planned. Two weeks have passed and quite a few mails between myself and Webpay's support but I didnt' move one centimeter.

To use this system I am using a library they created they are two steps: the first one is the "INTEGRATION" one, using generic certificates, I went thru this step without a problem. 
Then there is the "PRODUCTION" step where I needed to generate the .key .csr and .pfx Certificates. Which I did as I done before using Win64 OpenSSL [found here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) using those commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out 597034189528.key 2048

openssl req -new -key 597034189528.key -out 597034189528.csr

openssl x509 -req -days 1460 -in 597034189528.csr -signkey 597034189528.key -out 597034189528.crt

openssl pkcs12 -export -out 597034189528.pfx -inkey 597034189528.key -in 597034189528.crt
```

But when using the generated .PFX and running the code I got an error message saying **"Value was either too large or too small for a UInt64"**. This occurs when calling the library at this point

```
wsInitTransactionOutput result = webpay.getNormalTransaction().initTransaction(amount, buyOrder, sessionId, urlReturn, urlFinal);
```

Since then I tried generating and regenerating again the .PFX (using different versions of the Win64 OpenSSL) but it didn't change a thing Webpay's support keeps saying that there is something wrong with the certificate. 
Anybody around having had a similar issue with certificates ?

If someone feels like trying it please feel free to do so. [I uploaded here](https://www.corobori.com/sos/libwebpay-dotnet-master.zip) the library they are providing. Somewhere inside the ZIP file look for transbank.net and run a "webpay Normal" transaction. I am getting this:

[image: Error message and project]

At this stage I am blind, I guess the solution is so obvious that I can't see it.

Comment: In your `cert-normal.cs` I can see you have some typo `certificate.Add("environment", "PRODUCCION");`Is this intentionally done ?

Comment: Yes, that is in Spanish and it is how it is expected

Comment: I think I found the issue. In the library I got I have got this:  nodeX509SerialNumber.InnerText = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(certificateSignature.SerialNumber, 16)); I think it should be this  nodeX509SerialNumber.InnerText = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(certificateSignature.SerialNumber, 64));

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

It took time but I got to the bottom of this issue.

The certificate I originally generated was created using the latest version of OpenSSL, which was at that time version 1.1.0. The certificates that Transbank's library (the creator of WebPay) was expecting had to be generated with a OpenSSL 1.0.x version (serial number's size are different). I generated again the certificate with OpenSSL 1.0.2q:  the library behaved properly and payment went thru fine. I suggested to the provider that the documentation to be amended by specifying the OpenSSL's version.